# A call to delete [] crashes program, but not while debugging

Tags: c++, crash

Here is the code of a simple program which is supposed to read a text file which contains one word per line, dynamically allocate memory needed to store all the words, print them on the screen and deallocate the memory used.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class Dict {
 public:
 int size;
 char ** words;
 Dict (int, int*);
 ~Dict ();
};

Dict::Dict(int s,int* sizes) {
 int i;
 size=s;
 words = new char* [s];
 for (i=0;i<s;i++)
  words[i] = new char [sizes[i]];
}

Dict::~Dict() {
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
  delete [] words[i];
  printf("i=%d\n",i); // for debugging
  }
 delete [] words;
}

Dict loadDict (char* filename) {
 FILE* file;
 int n=0,i=0;
 int * sizes;
 char buff [64];

 file=fopen(filename,"r");
 while (!feof(file)) {
  n++;
  fscanf(file,"%*[^\n] \n");
 }
 sizes=new int [n];

 rewind(file);
 while (!feof(file)) {
  if (fscanf(file,"%s\n",buff)>0) {
   sizes[i]=strlen(buff);
   i++;
  }
 }

 rewind(file);
 Dict r(n,sizes);
 i=0;
 while (!feof(file)) {
  fscanf(file,"%s\n",r.words[i]);
  i++;
 }

 delete [] sizes;
 return r;
}

int main() {
 int i;
 Dict d=loadDict("dict.txt");
 for (i=0;i<d.size;i++)
 printf("%s|\n",d.words[i]);
 printf("%d DONE.\n",d.size);
 return 0;
}
```

The deallocating is done in the destructor of the Dict class. However, used on a sample text file with just a few words, the words are correctly printed, but the call to `~Dict` crashes the application after the execution of 3 lines of the form `delete [] words[i];`. If I use Code::Block's debugger and set a breakpoint on that line and tell it to continue on each breakpoint, the program terminates normally.

Since this is a really simple program, I hope there is some kind of easy answer or fix!

Comment: This is barely C++. If you're using C++, you might as well take advantage of some safety measures that are included in the standard library for you.

Comment: Try error checking your code.

Comment: Seeing as how the answers mention the RoT, I present this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is definitely wrong is that your code doesn't have a copy constructor and you are returning an object by value. This can lead to double destruction and, hence, double deletion of the date. Whether this happens drpends on whether copy construction is elided or not.

Additionally, you allocate for each string just enough characters to hold the string but not the null terminator. That is, to store a string `s` with length `strlen(s)` you need to allocate `strlen(s) + 1` characters.

I'd recommend using `std::vector<std::string>` instead: This avoids most of the problems.

Comment: Thank you. The evil zero character was apparently the cause for the crash.

Comment: The way you are returning your `Dict` object it is likely that the copy constructor is elided and, thus, I looked for another problem. Note that you also need to fix you copy constructor (and copy assignment)! There is no guarantee they are elided.

Answer (score 7):

The `Dict` class has dynamically allocated members but uses the default copy constructor and assignment operator which results in two instances of `Dict` pointing to the same `words` array when a copy of `Dict` is made, which happens when the `loadDict()` function is used. When one of the `Dict` instances is destructed it leaves the other `Dict` instance with a dangling pointer and will result in a double deletion of the `words` array and its elements.

See [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

If this it not a learning exercise use a [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead along with C++ streams. For example:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
...

std::ifstream in(filename);
std::string line;
while (in >> line) words.push_back(line);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was also a helpful answer and I will try to amend my bad c++ programming ways. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not following the rule of three:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

`Dict r` is destructed at the end of `loadDict` while a shallow copy of itself was returned to `main`. At the end of `main` the pointers are `delete`d again.

As often in C++, you don't need pointers here. Store a `std::vector<std::string>` in `Dict` and there will be no tricks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your codes:

1. You are not checking if the fopen return a valid pointer back. (well I got this because I try to run the code without the txt file)
2. You are returning a Dict obect, which will call the copy constructer and you didn't define one.
3. You used a assignment operater for Dict but you didn't define one.

You can try to change loadDict() to just return an array of size, and then pass that array into your Dict constructor. In this way you don't have to write the copy constructor and the assignment operater.